# C# - generic method that gets a generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class - `Class1<T>`,
and a regular class - `Class2`.

I want to create a generic method in Class2 that gets Class1 as a parameter.
I tried to do:

```
void DoSomething<T>(Class1<T> data) {
 ...
}
```

But I get an error:

> Error 25: The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '`Class1<T>`'.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you please add the code for Class1 to the question?

Comment: Can you show the class definition of `Class1` and `Class2` too? Also please read through the help about code formatting so you will know how to make Class1< T > instead look like `Class1<T>` when you write questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `where T : class` restriction on `Class<T>` so you just need to amend the method signature to match:

```
void DoSomething<T>(Class1<T> data) where T : class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the `Class1<T>` as below:

```
public class Class1<T> where T : class // here `T` is regarded as a reference type
{

}
```